# Twilio porting API invalid URL

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

When trying to send a CURL request to:

https://preview.twilio.com/porting/PortOrders

I get the following response when using our Master account credentials:

```
{
"code": 20404,
"message": "The requested resource /porting/PortOrders was not found",
"more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404",
"status": 404
}
```

Has the porting API url changed and the docs haven't been updated?

Comment: Last I heard it was in developer preview, maybe that ended. Probably their support would be the best place to check.

Comment: Does your account have access to the preview? If not, you need to apply for access here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScvGhhovDV7QLU9cYJkbr5zfsPFmnbs2m8ShhnWkXRayd_-TQ/viewform?c=0&w=1

Comment: I could had swear it has access but it didn't. Just got it working. Thanks